# Oracle SQL sum transactions by distinct customer id

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select the sum of transaction columns, count # of transactions, all by distinct customer ids. I have tried a few nested queries as well as something like the following:

```
select distinct(customer_id), sum(tran_amt), count(tran)
from tran_table
inner join tender_table;
```

The `tender_table` has the customer id so I have to join it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using group functions, but you don't have a "group by" clause, I think this will give you the correct answer:

SELECT customer_id, SUM(tran_amt), COUNT(tran) 
FROM   tran_table INNER JOIN tender_table
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want something like this:

```
select te.customer_id, sum(t.tran_amt), count(*)
from tran_table t inner join
     tender_table te
     on t.?? = te.??
group by te.customer_id;
```

You need `join` conditions and a `group by` clause.  The `??` is for the columns used for the `join`, which your question does not specify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

select tb_tran.customer_id, sum(tran_amt), count(tran)
  from tran_table tb_tran inner join tender_table tb_tender 
         on tb_tran.customer_id = tb_tender.customer_id 
  group by tb_tran.customer_id;